# how to prevent emacs from changing cursor position when scrolling the page

Tags: scroll, emacs, cursor, preserve

there is this annoying behavior in emacs which I don't know how to get rid of it.

lets say the current cursor position is on line 10 column 15.

now I need to quickly look up something far down the same buffer, I scroll down to that location and as I scroll down (or up) the cursor keeps moving and it loses its original location.

many people suggest to set a marker before scrolling but that is not a good solution, because you have to be always mindful of this fact before scrolling (which is impossible)

I know there should be a simple solution but I have not found it yet.
I'll appreciate your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Emacs doesn't allow you to scroll in such a way that your point disappears. I just took a quick look at `xdisp.c` and it looks like this is a fundamental assumption in the C code. This is different from some more recent editors (Sublime Text, VSCode etc).

*However*, the "many people" you mention actually have a reasonable point. If you're moving through the file by searching (`C-s the-thing-im-looking-for`) then Emacs will set a marker for you automatically.

I guess you could try adding a hook that set a marker at point whenever you scrolled? It wouldn't be trivial because you'd have to cope with things like not setting a load of markers through the file as your scroll dragged the cursor down. But my recommendation is probably to alter your workflow to match how Emacs wants to do things. In this case, it's probably a better approach than the modern editors it sounds like you're used to.

Answer (score 0):

An option that might or might not be useful is [`scroll-preserve-screen-position`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Scrolling.html). The description is somewhat hard to understand, but a net result is that if you mainly scroll using `C-v/M-v`, the point will *visually* stay at the same place on the screen (so if you do *e.g.* `C-v C-v M-v M-v`, the point will come back to its original position.

However, note that many commands do push a mark before they jump: `isearch`, `end-of-buffer`, `imenu`, `xref-find-definition` ... In all those cases, you can then press `C-u C-SPC` (the same command that you use to set the mark but called with a prefix argument) to pop the mark (concretely, jump to the last mark). If you need to jump back more than once, you can set the variable `set-mark-command-repeat-pop` to `t`, so that you only need to do `C-u` once and then repeatedly press `C-SPC` to pop more and more marks from the mark ring.

In general, there are better ways to navigate a buffer than scrolling in the wild; the cases where you *do* need to scroll, starting from "your current" point are (or should/could be ...) sufficiently rare that you know beforehand that you will be spending a possibly long time "looking around" in the buffer. It is then quite fast to set a mark, do your stuff somewhere else, and `C-u <mash C-SPC as often as needed>` until you get back to your initial point.